# PHP - MS SQL Server pass xml argument from PHP code

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I am using MS SQL Server with PHP and one of the columns in SQL Server stored procedure is of type xml. I am running a foreach statement in PHP to iterate the array values and create a string with xml tags and passing the string variable to loadXML and saveXML. I can see the output in logs with type as string.

XML Format to create:

```
'<paramList><i v=".Production"/><i v="IFT"/></paramList>'
```

PHP Code to create the XML tags:

```
            $create_env = array();
            if(is_array($this->env_ref)) {
               $env_values = array_values($this->env_ref);
               foreach($env_values as $k => $v) {
                   $create_env[] = array("id" => $v);
               }
               $env_args = $create_env;

               $env_xml_args = '<paramList>';
               foreach($env_args as $p) {
                 foreach($p as $_p => $_q) {
                   $modify_env  = strpos($_q, ".", 0);
                     if($modify_env !== false) {
                        $modify_env = $modify_env + 1;
                        $extract_env = substr($_q, $modify_env, strlen($_q));
                     } else {
                         $extract_env = $_q;
                     }
                     $env_xml_args .= '<i v='."'".$extract_env."'".'/>';
                 }
               }
               $env_xml_args .= '</paramList>';
            }
            $env_str_args = $env_xml_args;

            $t_xml = new DOMDocument();
            $t_xml->loadXML($env_str_args);
            $env_args = $t_xml->saveXML($t_xml->documentElement);
```

Stored procedure to execute in PHP:

```
            $session_search      = array();
            $this->dbinstance    = $instance;
            $this->formatter     = "{call %s.%s.%s(?)}";
            $this->sessionSearch = sprintf($this->formatter, DB_NAME, DB_OWNER, SEARCH);

            $sql = $this->sessionSearch;

            $args = array($event_id_args, $proj_args, $event_name_args, $emp_args, $snap_ticket_args, $start_period_dt_args, $finish_period_dt_args, $is_archived_args, $sort_order_args, $publish_flag_args, $is_archived_proj_args, $identity_id_args, $env_args, $state_args);

            error_log(var_dump($args));

            $searchStatement = sqlsrv_prepare($this->dbinstance, $sql, $args);

            if(!$searchStatement) {
               return False;
            }

            $searchExecuteStatement = sqlsrv_execute($searchStatement);

            if(!$searchExecuteStatement) {
               return False;
            } else {
                while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($searchStatement, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                 $session_search[]     = array("event_id" => $rows["id"], "event_name" => $rows["NAME"], "event_date_from" => $rows["start"], "event_date_to" => $rows['finish'], "event_project_id" => $rows["PROJECTID"], "event_env_id" => $rows["ENVID"], "event_notes" => $rows["notes"], "event_epm" => $rows["epmname"]);
                }
            }
            sqlsrv_free_stmt($searchStatement);
            sqlsrv_close($this->dbinstance);

            return $session_search;
```

PHP var_dump output:

```
string(55) "<paramList><i v=".Production"/><i v="IFT"/></paramList>"
```

The stored procedure executes without any errors and returns all the result set. When i execute the stored procedure in SQL server management tool with static input as shown above it retrieves only the matching records of the input.

I don't have much knowledge on SQL Server because i used only MySQL as backend to PHP earlier. can anyone please help with a solution about how to pass XML as input to the column.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  You say "The stored procedure executes without any errors and returns all the result set".  Is that a problem?

Comment: yes, by default all the parameters are NULL and the stored procedure returns 13K+ rows. If i pass the xml input as parameter, it fetches only 60 records based on the environments in the above code.

Comment: If the xml input parameter is invalid, the stored procedure should throw error. In this scenario, i am unable to debug about why the stored procedure is not accepting the xml input parameter when i run using PHP code.

Comment: Seems like there are 14 values in your `$args` array but only one `?` placeholder in your `$sql`. Perhaps review the [sqlsrv_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) documentation?

Comment: I am passing an array instead of individual arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it on my own. The problem is, SQL stored procedure needs the keys along with values when the INPUT is passed to the stored procedure. I was only passing the values.